# Sorting file names by length of the file name

Tags: unix, sorting

`ls` displays the files available in a directory. I want the file names to be displayed based on the length of the file name.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this

```
for i in `ls`; do LEN=`expr length $i`; echo $LEN $i; done | sort -n
```

Comment: I think it is sorting based on file size , I want it to be sorted based on the length of filename

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way is just:

```
$ ls | perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>'
```

Comment: Raghuram's answer above didn't work for me on FreeBSD in bash shell, but this one did.  Gotta love perl.  Thanks.

Comment: I like that this unlike many of the other answers don't include the length of the filename in the output.

Comment: Useful: `ls | perl -e 'print sort { length($a) <=> length($b) } <>'`  I wanted the opposite order with the longest filenames at the bottom

Answer (score 4):

make test files:

```
mkdir -p test; cd test 
touch short-file-name  medium-file-name  loooong-file-name
```

the script:

```
ls |awk '{print length($0)"\t"$0}' |sort -n |cut --complement -f1
```

output:

```
short-file-name
medium-file-name
loooong-file-name
```

Comment: The first two solution works fine . Thanks all for the response.

Comment: `ls|awk '{print length($0)"\t"$0}' |sort -n|cut -f2` works with BusyBox v1.01

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in *; do printf "%d\t%s\n" "${#i}" "$i"; done | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

Comment: Nice! Does not need perl. Works for filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Command:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | perl -F'/\0/' -ape '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | sed 's#/#/\\n/#g'
```

Alternate version of command that's easier to read:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | \
perl -F'/\0/' -ape \
  '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | \
sed 's#/#/\\n/#g'
```

---

### [Not Parsing `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) Output <s>AND Benchmarking</s>

There are good answers here. However, if one wants to follow the advice [not to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), here are some ways to get the job done. *This will especially take care of the situation where you have spaces in filenames.* <s>I'm going to benchmark everything here as well as the paring-`ls` examples.</s> (Hopefully I get to that, soon.) I've put a bunch of somewhat-random filenames that I've downloaded from different places over the last 25 years or so -- 73 to begin with. All 73 are 'normal' filenames, with only alphanumeric characters, underscores, dots, and hyphens. I'll add 2 more which I make now (in order to show problems with some sorts).

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ mkdir ../dir_w_fnames__spaces

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ cp ./* ../dir_w_fnames__spaces/

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ cd ../dir_w_fnames__spaces/

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ touch "just one file with a really long filename that can throw off some counts bla so there"

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ mkdir ../dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ cp ./* ../dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines/

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ cd ../dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines/

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ touch $'w\nlf.aa'
```

This one, i.e. the filename,

```sh
w
lf.aa
```

stands for **w**ith **l**ine**f**eed - I make it like this to make it easier to see the problems. I don't know why I chose `.aa` as the file extension, other than the fact that it made this filename length easily visible in the sorts.

Now, I'm going back to the `orig_dir_73` directory; <s>just trust me that this directory only contains files.</s> We'll use a surefire way to get the number of files.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ du --inodes
74      .

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ # The 74th inode is for the current directory, '.'; we have 73 files
```

There's a more surefire way, which doesn't depend on the directory only having files and doesn't require you to remember the extra `'.'` inode. I just looked through the `man` page, did some research, and did some experimentation. This command is

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

or, in more-readable fashion,

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

Let's find out how many files we have

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
73

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ cd ../dir_w_fnames__spaces

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
74

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ cd ../dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines/

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
75
```

(See  <sup>[ 1 ]</sup>  for details and an edge case for a previous solution that led to the command here now.)

I'll be switching back and forth between these directories; just make sure you pay attention to the path - I won't note every switch.

---

#### ** Usable even with weird filenames (containing spaces, linefeeds, etc.)*

#### 1a. Perl à la @tchrist with Additions

***Using*** `find` ***with null separator. Hacking around newlines in a filename.***

Command:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | perl -F'/\0/' -ape '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | sed 's#/#/\\n/#g'
```

Alternate version of command that's easier to read:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | \
perl -F'/\0/' -ape \
  '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | \
sed 's#/#/\\n/#g'
```

I'll actually show part of the sort results to show that the following command works. I'll also show how I'm checking that weird filenames aren't breaking anything.

Note that one wouldn't usually use `head` or `tail` if one wants the whole, sorted list (hopefully, it's not a [sordid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sordid) list). I'm using those commands for demonstration.

First, 'normal' filenames.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | \
perl -F'/\0/' -ape \
  '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | \
sed 's#/#/\\n/#g' | head -n 5
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt
17f09d51d6280fb8393d5f321f344f616c461a57a8b9cf9cc3099f906b567c992.txt

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | \
perl -F'/\0/' -ape \
  '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | \
sed 's#/#/\\n/#g' | tail -n 5
137.csv
13.csv
o6.dat
3.csv
a.dat

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ # No spaces in fnames, so...

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
73
```

- **Works** for **normal filenames**

Next: spaces

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | \
perl -F'/\0/' -ape \
  '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | \
sed 's#/#/\\n/#g' | head -n 5
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
just one file with a really long filename that can throw off some counts bla so there
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt
```

- **Works** for **filenames containing spaces**

Next: newline

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | \
perl -F'/\0/' -ape \
  '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | \
sed 's#/#/\\n/#g' | tail -8
Lk3f.png
LOqU.txt
137.csv
w/\n/lf.aa
13.csv
o6.dat
3.csv
a.dat
```

If you prefer, you can also change this command a bit, so the filename comes out with the linefeed "evaluated".

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | tr '\n' '/' | \
perl -F'/\0/' -ape \
  '$_=join("\n", sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @F)' | \
sed 's#/#\n#g' | tail -8
LOqU.txt
137.csv
w
lf.aa
13.csv
o6.dat
3.csv
a.dat
```

In either case, you will know, due to what we've been doing, that the list is sorted, even though it doesn't appear so.

(Visual on not appearing sorted by filename length)

```
********
********
*******
**********       <-- Visual Problem
*****
*****
****
****
```

OR

```
********
*******
*                <-- Visual
****             <-- Problems
*****
*****
****
****
```

- **Works** for **filenames containing newlines**

---

#### ** 2a. Very Close, but Doesn't Keep Newline Filename Together - à la @cpasm*

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ for i in *; do printf "%d\t%s\n" "${#i}" "$i"; done | sort -n | cut -f2- | head
lf.aa
3.csv
a.dat
13.csv
o6.dat
137.csv
w
1UG5.txt
1uWj.txt
2Ese.txt

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ for i in *; do printf "%d\t%s\n" "${#i}" "$i"; done | sort -n | cut -f2- | tail -5
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
just one file with a really long filename that can throw off some counts bla so there
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
```

Note, for the `head` part, that the `w` in

```
w(\n)
lf.aa
```

is in the correct, sorted position for the 6-character-long filename that it is. However, the `lf.aa` is not in a logical place.

---

#### ** Less-Easily Breakable (only '\n' and possibly command characters could be a problem)*

#### 1b. Perl à la @tchrist with `find`, not `ls`

***Using*** `find` ***with null separator and*** `xargs`.

Command:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -I'{}' -0 echo "{}" | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>'
```

Alternate version of command that's easier to read:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -I'{}' -0 \
    echo "{}" | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | \
        perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>'
```

Let's go for it.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -I'{}' -0 \
    echo "{}" | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | \
      perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | head -n 5
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt
17f09d51d6280fb8393d5f321f344f616c461a57a8b9cf9cc3099f906b567c992.txt

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/orig_dir_73
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -I'{}' -0 \
    echo "{}" | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | \
      perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | tail -8
IKlT.txt
Lk3f.png
LOqU.txt
137.csv
13.csv
o6.dat
3.csv
a.dat
```

- **Works** for **normal filenames**

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -I'{}' -0 \
    echo "{}" | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | \
      perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | head -n 5
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
just one file with a really long filename that can throw off some counts bla so there
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt
```

- **Works** for **filenames containing spaces**

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -I'{}' -0 \
    echo "{}" | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | \
      perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | head -n 5
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
just one file with a really long filename that can throw off some counts bla so there
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -I'{}' -0 \
    echo "{}" | sed 's#\./.*/\([^/]\+\)\./$#\1#g' | 
      perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | tail -8
LOqU.txt
137.csv
13.csv
o6.dat
3.csv
a.dat
lf.aa
w
```

#### WARNING

- **BREAKS** for **filenames containing newlines**

#### 1c. Good for normal filenames and filenames with spaces, but breakable with filenames containing newlines - à la @tchrist

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ ls | perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | head -n 5
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
just one file with a really long filename that can throw off some counts bla so there
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ ls | perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | tail -8
LOqU.txt
137.csv
13.csv
o6.dat
3.csv
a.dat
lf.aa
w
```

#### 3a. Good for normal filenames and filenames with spaces, but breakable with filenames containing newlines - à la @Peter_O

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ ls | awk '{print length($0)"\t"$0}' | sort -n | cut --complement -f1 | head -n 8
w
3.csv
a.dat
lf.aa
13.csv
o6.dat
137.csv
1UG5.txt

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ ls | awk '{print length($0)"\t"$0}' | sort -n | cut --complement -f1 | tail -5
83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt
79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
just one file with a really long filename that can throw off some counts bla so there
oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
```

---

#### ** More-Easily Breakable*

#### 4a. Good for normal filenames - à la @Raghuram

This version is breakable with filenames containing either spaces or newlines (or both).

I do want to add that I do like the display of the actual string length, if just for analysis purposes.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ for i in `ls`; do LEN=`expr length $i`; echo $LEN $i; done | sort -n | head -n 20
1 a
1 w
2 so
3 bla
3 can
3 off
3 one
4 file
4 just
4 long
4 some
4 that
4 with
5 3.csv
5 a.dat
5 lf.aa
5 there
5 throw
6 13.csv
6 counts

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /home/bballdave025/dir_w_fnames__spaces_and_newlines
$ for i in `ls`; do LEN=`expr length $i`; echo $LEN $i; done | sort -n | tail -5
69 17f09d51d6280fb8393d5f321f344f616c461a57a8b9cf9cc3099f906b567c992.txt
70 83dfee2e0f8560dbd2a681a5a40225fd260d3b428b962dcfb75d17e43a5fdec9_1.txt
76 79496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538sfp6m8o1m53hlwlfja.dat
87 oinwrxK2ea1sfp6m8o49255f679496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d343538b3e0.csv
238 68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f71526c586e654345744a365939773d3d2d3435383139353437362e313464633462356336326266656365303439363432373931333139382e676966.txt
```

---

### Explanation of Some Commands

For now, I'll only note that, with the works-for-all `find` command, I used `'/'` for the newline substitute because it is the only character that is illegal in a filename both on *NIX and Windows.

---

**Note(s)**

<sup>[ 1 ]</sup>  The command used,

```sh
du --inodes --files0-from=<(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | \
awk '{sum+=int($1)}END{print sum}'
```

will work in this case, because when there is a file with a newline, and therefore an "extra" line in the output of the `find` command, `awk`'s `int` function will evaluate to 0 for the text of that link. Specifically, for our newline-containing filename, `w\nlf.aa`, i.e.

```sh
w
lf.aa
```

we will get

```sh
$ awk '{print int($1)}' < <(echo "lf.aa")
0
```

If you have a situation where the filename is something like

`firstline\n3 and some other\n1\n2\texciting\n86stuff.jpg`

i.e.

```sh
firstline
3 and some other
1
2     exciting
86stuff.jpg
```

well, I guess the computer has beaten me. If anyone has a solution, I'd be glad to hear it.

**Edit** I think I'm way too deep into this question. from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679459/6505499) and experimentation, I got this command (I don't understand all the details, but I've tested it pretty well.)

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

More readably:

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

Comment: `perl -wE'say for sort { length $a <=> length $b } glob "*"'` Throw in `grep { -f }` between `map` and `glob` to include only plain files.  (Not meant to compete with your study :)

Comment: @zdim that is awesome. That doesn't compete with my study, it furthers my study. I love SO, because I'm always learning new things.

Comment: Using find, xargs and perl. What a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ls --color=never --indicator-style=none | awk '{print length, $0}' |
sort -n | cut -d" " -f2-
```

To see it in action, create some files

```
% touch a ab abc
```

and some directories

```
% mkdir d de def
```

Output of the normal ls command

```
% ls
a  ab  abc  d/  de/  def/
```

Output from the proposed command

```
% ls --color=never --indicator-style=none | awk '{print length, $0}' |
sort -n | cut -d" " -f2-
a
d
ab
de
abc
def
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix
Version sort will help

```
ls -1v
```