# Is there a bash command which counts files?

Tags: bash

Is there a bash command which counts the number of files that match a pattern?

For example, I want to get the count of all files in a directory which match this pattern: `log*`

Comment: We keep getting new answers which don't work for nontrivial file names. If you want to post a new answer, please read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 first

Answer (score 379, accepted):

This simple one-liner should work in any shell, not just bash:

```
ls -1q log* | wc -l
```

ls -1q will give you one line per file, even if they contain whitespace or special characters such as newlines.

The output is piped to wc -l, which counts the number of lines.

Comment: you just have * on the opposite side but this works thx a lot

Comment: I would not use `-l`, since that requires `stat(2)` on each file and for the purposes of counting adds nothing.

Comment: I would not use `ls`, since it creates a child process.  `log*` is expanded by the shell, not `ls`, so a simple `echo` would do.

Comment: Except an echo will not work if you have file names with spaces or special characters.

Comment: I also get "ls: cannot access log*: No such file or directory" if no files match. wc does not count this error as a line since it is output via stderr rather than stdout. Also, the -l (for long) can be replaced by -1f (for files-only, one per line). Try "2>/dev/null ls -1f log* | wc -l" if cleanliness is important.

Comment: Actually "ls -l" doesn't print files one per line when the output is piped. `touch abc$'\n'def; ls abc*def | wc -l` prints 2 even though if you don't pipe it, it'll show `abc?def`. `ls -1f` has the same problem.

Comment: Looks like you're right @mogsie, funny, I'm sure I tested that back in 2012. Updated to defer to Mat's answer if fines with newlines need to be catered for.

Comment: @camh is right, `ls -l` is an overkill. `ls -1` is enough.

Comment: @WalterTross That's true (not that efficiency was a requirement of the original question). I also just found that -q takes care of files with newlines, even when the output is not the terminal. And these flags are supported by all the platforms and shells I've tested on. Updating the answer, thanks to you and camh for the input!

Comment: wc -l count lines. I am sure there must be a better solution which does not read all the filnames.

Comment: If there's a directory called `logs` in the directory in question, then the _contents_ of that logs directory will be counted too.  This is probably not intentional.

Comment: If you are in an interactive bash shell, I'd recommend using `command ls -1q` to bypass any function or alias wrappers that might set undesirable switches (*lots* of default `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` configurations wrap `ls` in an alias with default switches). Adding `-U` or `-f` would make it faster on large directories, but no more correct (as long as you used `command` to avoid aliases; `-f` might protect you from some aliases if you forget to use `command`).

Comment: This will work with any POSIX shell and does not parse the output of `ls`, which is a slippery slope bad practice: `set -- log*; echo $#`

Comment: I am using bash (with `oh-my-bash` too) and for a directory containing 3 subdirectories `log1`, `log2`, and `log3`, the command `ls -1q log* | wc -l` is returning 5, not 3. This seems to be because `ls` is listing the files separated by blank lines. Any ideas how to correct this?

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson In your case you have directories matching the `log*` pattern (this is different to the OP's case), so their contents will also be included. You can add the `-d` argument to prevent `ls` from displaying directory contents, e.g.: `ls -1qd`

Comment: Thank-you @Daniel adding the `-d` argument did the trick :)

Comment: I think one needs to redirect the stderr to /dev/null so that the result will be accurate when the directory is empty

Comment: This answer does not work if there is no `log*` file. adding `2>/dev/null` and using `wc -c` instead would be better

Comment: For large directories this approach would never end up with a response: `ls` internally does implicit sorting by file name, with all the disvantages that this can bring. I think that this cannot be the accepted answer, as it can potentially hang up waiting for the OS to return the whole list and then sorting, before counting a very long list full of words full of useless characters, looking for '\n's. See [@Will-Vousden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11307341/5152432), which works really faster and with far less memory

Comment: This is buggy. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61613373/5889538).

Answer (score 88):

Lots of answers here, but some don't take into account

- file names with spaces, newlines, or control characters in them
- file names that start with hyphens (imagine a file called `-l`)
- hidden files, that start with a dot (if the glob was `*.log` instead of `log*`
- directories that match the glob (e.g. a directory called `logs` that matches `log*`)
- empty directories (i.e. the result is 0)
- extremely large directories (listing them all could exhaust memory)

Here's a solution that handles all of them:

```
ls 2>/dev/null -Ubad1 -- log* | wc -l
```

Explanation:

- `-U` causes `ls` to not sort the entries, meaning it doesn't need to load the entire directory listing in memory
- `-b` prints C-style escapes for nongraphic characters, crucially causing newlines to be printed as `\n`.
- `-a` prints out all files, even hidden files (not strictly needed when the glob `log*` implies no hidden files)
- `-d` prints out directories without attempting to list the *contents* of the directory, which is what `ls` normally would do
- `-1` makes sure that it's on one column (ls does this automatically when writing to a pipe, so it's not strictly necessary)
- `2>/dev/null` redirects stderr so that if there are 0 log files, ignore the error message. (Note that `shopt -s nullglob` would cause `ls` to list the entire working directory instead.)
- `wc -l` consumes the directory listing as it's being generated, so the output of `ls` is never in memory at any point in time.
- `--` File names are separated from the command using `--` so as not to be understood as arguments to `ls` (in case `log*` is removed)

The shell *will* expand `log*` to the full list of files, which may exhaust memory if it's a lot of files, so then running it through grep is be better:

```
ls -Uba1 | grep ^log | wc -l
```

This last one handles extremely large directories of files without using a lot of memory (albeit it does use a subshell).  The `-d` is no longer necessary, because it's only listing the contents of the current directory.

Comment: I\`m almost 5 years late but still I\`d like to point out that `grep` can count lines as well, rendering `wc -l` unnecessary. The resulting command would look like this: `ls -Uba1 | grep -c ^log`. Nevertheless, the original answer is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 80):

For a recursive search:

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' -printf x | wc -c
```

`wc -c` will count the number of characters in the output of `find`, while `-printf x` tells `find` to print a single `x` for each result. This avoids any problems with files with odd names which contain newlines etc.

For a non-recursive search, do this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.log' -printf x | wc -c
```

Comment: FYI if you simply leave out `-name '*.log'` then it will count all files, which is what I needed for my use case. Also the -maxdepth flag is extremely useful, thanks!

Comment: This does great in avoiding problems with any type of special characters!

Comment: I benchmarked this one against the other approaches, and _(on my machine)_ **this one is the fastest** by a significant margin—the runner-up was the less-safe default `find` output piped into `wc -l`, and that was ~2x slower than your solution.

So Kudos! `^v^`

Comment: probably the most correct flag to use with `wc` is `-m`, which counts characters instead of bytes, but yes, I think that your one is the most effective solution

Answer (score 70):

You can do this safely (i.e. won't be bugged by files with spaces or `\n` in their name) with bash:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ logfiles=(*.log)
$ echo ${#logfiles[@]}
```

You need to enable [`nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) so that you don't get the literal `*.log` in the `$logfiles` [array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) if no files match. (See [How to "undo" a 'set -x'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310957/how-to-undo-a-set-x/310963) for examples of how to safely reset it.)

Comment: Perhaps explicitly point out that this is a Bash-*only* answer, especially for new visitors who are not yet entirely up to speed on the [Difference between sh and bash](/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: Note: Replacing `*.log` with just `*` will count directories. If the files you wish to enumerate have the traditional naming convention of `name.extension`, use `*.*`.

Comment: An explanation of what the [@] means would be helpful

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer for this question is wrong, but I have low rep so can't add a comment to it.

The correct answer to this question is given by Mat:

```
shopt -s nullglob
logfiles=(*.log)
echo ${#logfiles[@]}
```

The problem with the accepted answer is that wc -l counts the number of newline characters, and counts them even if they print to the terminal as '?' in the output of 'ls -l'. This means that the accepted answer FAILS when a filename contains a newline character. I have tested the suggested command:

```
ls -l log* | wc -l
```

and it erroneously reports a value of 2 even if there is only 1 file matching the pattern whose name happens to contain a newline character. For example:

```
touch log$'\n'def
ls log* -l | wc -l
```

Answer (score 11):

## An important comment

(not enough reputation to comment)

This is **BUGGY**:

```
ls -1q some_pattern | wc -l
```

If `shopt -s nullglob` happens to be set, it prints the number of **ALL** regular files, not just the ones with the pattern (tested on CentOS-8 and Cygwin). Who knows what other meaningless bugs does `ls` have?

This is **CORRECT** and much faster:

```
shopt -s nullglob; files=(some_pattern); echo ${#files[@]};
```

It does the expected job.

---

And the running times differ.

The 1st: `0.006` on CentOS, and `0.083` on Cygwin (in case it is used with care).

The 2nd: `0.000` on CentOS, and `0.003` on Cygwin.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my one liner for this.

```
 file_count=$( shopt -s nullglob ; set -- $directory_to_search_inside/* ; echo $#)
```

Comment: It took me some googling to understand, but this is nice! So `set -- ` is not doing anything except getting us ready for `$#`, that _stores the number of command-line arguments that were passed to the shell program_

Comment: @xverges Yes,  "shopt -s nullglob" is for not counting hidden files(.files). set -- is for storing/setting number of  positional parameters(num of files, in this case). and #$ for displaying the number of positional parameters(files count).

Comment: A correct syntax and POSIX compliant version of your implementation, without even a sub-shell spawned: `set -- "$directory_to_search_inside/"*; [ $# -eq 1 -a ! -e "$1" ] && shift; file_count=$#`

Answer (score 8):

If you have a lot of files and you don't want to use the elegant `shopt -s nullglob` and bash array solution, you can use find and so on as long as you don't print out the file name (which might contain newlines).

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "log*" -not -name ".*" -printf '%i\n' | wc -l
```

This will find all files that match log* and that don't start with `.*` — The "not name .*" is redunant, but it's important to note that the default for "ls" is to not show dot-files, but the default for find is to include them.

This is a correct answer, and handles any type of file name you can throw at it, because the file name is never passed around between commands.

But, the `shopt nullglob` answer is the best answer!

Comment: You probably should update your original answer instead of answering again.

Comment: I think using `find` vs using `ls` are two different ways of solving the problem.  `find` is not always present on a machine, but `ls` usually is,

Comment: But then a box of lard which doesn't have `find` probably doesn't have all those fancy options for `ls` either.

Comment: Note also how this extends to a whole directory tree if you take out the `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: Note this solution will count files inside hidden directories in its count.`find` does this by default. This can create confusion if one doesn't realize there's a hidden child folder, and may make it advantageous to use `ls` in some circumstances, which does not report hidden files by default.

Answer (score 5):

You can define such a command easily, using a shell function. This method does not require any external program and does not spawn any child process. It does not attempt hazardous `ls` parsing and handles “special” characters (whitespaces, newlines, backslashes and so on) just fine. It only relies on the file name expansion mechanism provided by the shell. It is compatible with at least sh, bash and zsh.

The line below defines a function called `count` which prints the number of arguments with which it has been called.

```
count() { echo $#; }
```

Simply call it with the desired pattern:

```
count log*
```

For the result to be correct when the globbing pattern has no match, the shell option `nullglob` (or `failglob` — which is the default behavior on zsh) must be set at the time expansion happens. It can be set like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob    # for sh / bash
setopt nullglob      # for zsh
```

Depending on what you want to count, you might also be interested in the shell option `dotglob`.

Unfortunately, with bash at least, it is not easy to set these options locally. If you don’t want to set them globally, the most straightforward solution is to use the function in this more convoluted manner:

```
( shopt -s nullglob ; shopt -u failglob ; count log* )
```

If you want to recover the lightweight syntax `count log*`, or if you really want to avoid spawning a subshell, you may hack something along the lines of:

```
# sh / bash:
# the alias is expanded before the globbing pattern, so we
# can set required options before the globbing gets expanded,
# and restore them afterwards.
count() {
    eval "$_count_saved_shopts"
    unset _count_saved_shopts
    echo $#
}
alias count='
    _count_saved_shopts="$(shopt -p nullglob failglob)"
    shopt -s nullglob
    shopt -u failglob
    count'
```

---

As a bonus, this function is of a more general use. For instance:

```
count a* b*          # count files which match either a* or b*
count $(jobs -ps)    # count stopped jobs (sh / bash)
```

By turning the function into a script file (or an equivalent C program), callable from the PATH, it can also be composed with programs such as `find` and `xargs`:

```
find "$FIND_OPTIONS" -exec count {} \+    # count results of a search
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the -R option to find the files along with those inside the recursive directories

```
ls -R | wc -l // to find all the files

ls -R | grep log | wc -l // to find the files which contains the word log
```

*you can use patterns on the grep*

Comment: is not recommended to do it this way. Explanation: github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2010

Answer (score 2):

I've given this answer a lot of thought, especially given the [don't-parse-ls stuff](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). At first, I tried

```
<WARNING! DID NOT WORK>
```

```sh
du --inodes --files0-from=<(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | awk '{sum+=int($1)}END{print sum}'
```

```
</WARNING! DID NOT WORK>
```

which worked if there was only a filename like

```sh
touch $'w\nlf.aa'
```

but failed if I made a filename like this

```sh
touch $'firstline\n3 and some other\n1\n2\texciting\n86stuff.jpg'
```

I finally came up with what I'm putting below. Note I was trying to get a count of all files in the directory (not including any subdirectories). I think it, along with the answers by @Mat and @Dan_Yard , as well as having at least most of the requirements set out by @mogsie (I'm not sure about memory.) I think the answer by @mogsie is correct, but I always try to stay away from parsing `ls` unless it's an extremely specific situation.

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

More readably:

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

This is doing a find specifically for files, delimiting the output with a null character (to avoid problems with spaces and linefeeds), then counting the number of null characters. The number of files will be one less than the number of null characters, since there will be a null character at the end.

To answer the OP's question, there are two cases to consider

1) Non-recursive search:

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "log*" -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

2) Recursive search. Note that what's inside the `-name` parameter might need to be changed for slightly different behavior (hidden files, etc.).

```sh
awk -F"\0" '{print NF-1}' < \
  <(find . -type f -name "log*" -print0) | \
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

If anyone would like to comment on how these answers compare to those I've mentioned in this answer, please do.

---

Note, I got to this thought process while getting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217769/6505499).

Comment: I don't think Awk can reliably be expected to cope correctly with null bytes either, though.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say, @tripleee, but I want to be sure. Are you saying that a filename containing a null character will cause problems when passed to `awk -F'\0'`? That would absolutely be the case, and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: However, with more reflection, a filename can't have a null character, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205087/how-can-i-create-a-file-with-null-bytes-in-the-filename . Could you further explain what you mean, @tripleee ? If this answer doesn't work for certain nontrivial filenames, I don't want to keep it here.

Comment: The `-print0` specifically adds a null byte between file names as the only separator which absolutely cannot be part of the filename itself. Some Awk versions can deal with that, but others can't. For more background, perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with standard POSIX shell grammar.

Here is a simple `count_entries` function:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

count_entries()
{
  # Emulating Bash nullglob 
  # If argument 1 is not an existing entry
  if [ ! -e "$1" ]
    # argument is a returned pattern
    # then shift it out
    then shift
  fi
  echo $#
}
```

for a compact definition:

```bash
count_entries(){ [ ! -e "$1" ]&&shift;echo $#;}
```

Featured POSIX compatible file counter by type:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

count_files()
# Count the file arguments matching the file operator
# Synopsys:
# count_files operator FILE [...]
# Arguments:
# $1: The file operator
#   Allowed values:
#   -a FILE    True if file exists.
#   -b FILE    True if file is block special.
#   -c FILE    True if file is character special.
#   -d FILE    True if file is a directory.
#   -e FILE    True if file exists.
#   -f FILE    True if file exists and is a regular file.
#   -g FILE    True if file is set-group-id.
#   -h FILE    True if file is a symbolic link.
#   -L FILE    True if file is a symbolic link.
#   -k FILE    True if file has its `sticky' bit set.
#   -p FILE    True if file is a named pipe.
#   -r FILE    True if file is readable by you.
#   -s FILE    True if file exists and is not empty.
#   -S FILE    True if file is a socket.
#   -t FD      True if FD is opened on a terminal.
#   -u FILE    True if the file is set-user-id.
#   -w FILE    True if the file is writable by you.
#   -x FILE    True if the file is executable by you.
#   -O FILE    True if the file is effectively owned by you.
#   -G FILE    True if the file is effectively owned by your group.
#   -N FILE    True if the file has been modified since it was last read.
# $@: The files arguments
# Output:
#   The number of matching files
# Return:
#   1: Unknown file operator
{
  operator=$1
  shift
  case $operator in
    -[abcdefghLkprsStuwxOGN])
      for arg; do
        # If file is not of required type
        if ! test "$operator" "$arg"; then
          # Shift it out
          shift
        fi
      done
      echo $#
      ;;
    *)
      printf 'Invalid file operator: %s\n' "$operator" >&2
      return 1
      ;;
  esac
}

count_files "$@"
```

Example usages:

```bash
count_files -f log*.txt
count_files -d datadir*
```

**Alternate count non-directory entries without a loop:**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Creates strings of as many dots as expanded arguments

# dotted string for entries matching star pattern
star=$(printf '%.0s.' ./*)
# dotted string for entries matching star slash pattern (directories)
star_dir=$(printf '%.0s.' ./*/)
# dotted string for entries matching dot star pattern
dot_star=$(printf '%.0s.' ./.*)
# dotted string for entries matching dot star slash pattern (directories)
dot_star_dir=$(printf '%.0s.' ./.*/)

# Print pattern matches count excluding directories matches
printf 'Files count: %d\n' $((
  ${#star} - ${#star_dir} +
  ${#dot_star} - ${#dot_star_dir}
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic Bash function you can use in your scripts.

```sh
    # @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11307382/430062
    function countFiles {
        shopt -s nullglob
        logfiles=($1)
        echo ${#logfiles[@]}
    }

    FILES_COUNT=$(countFiles "$file-*")
```

Comment: See: [`count_entries(){ [ $# -eq 1 ]&&[ ! -e "$1" ]&&shift;echo $#;}
`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64466042/7939871). It does not need `nullglob`, so it is 100% POSIX grammar.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -1 log* | wc -l
```

Which means list one file per line and then pipe it to word count command with parameter switching to count lines.

Comment: "-1" option is not necessary when piping the ls output. But you might want to hide ls error message if no file matches the pattern. I suggest " ls log* 2>/dev/null | wc -l ".

Comment: The discussion under [Daniel's answer](/a/11307364/874188) is relevant here too. This works fine when you don't have matching directories or file names with newlines, but a good answer should at least point out these boundary conditions, and a great answer should not have them. Many bugs are because somebody copy/pasted code they didn't understand; so pointing out the flaws at least helps them understand what to watch out for. (Granted, many more bugs happen because they ignored the caveats and then things changed after they thought the code was probably good enough for their purpose.)

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I always do:

> ls log* | awk 'END{print NR}'

Comment: `awk 'END{print NR}'` should be equivalent to `wc -l`.

Comment: We keep getting new answers which don't work for nontrivial file names. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score -3):

To count everything just pipe ls to word count line:

```
ls | wc -l
```

To count with pattern, pipe to grep first:

```
ls | grep log | wc -l
```

Comment: is not recommended to do it this way. Explanation: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2010