# What's the fastest way to count files?

Tags: bash

We just installed a mass filer device that we want to store data from our suppliers on. They FTP files to it every day and right now, we've about 60,000+ files.

Doing `find . -name '*TXT' -exec ls '{}' \; | wc -l` will work albeit very slowly.

Is there a faster way to count files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just

```
find . -name '*TXT' | wc -l
```

? Your current command is unnecessarily spawning `ls` for *each* file, and that process spawning in itself will be very slow. A quick test on my system would suggest a 40x speed up.

Comment: Brian, your explanation makes complete sense. No wonder it's so slow. Thank you. Accepted and voted up.

Comment: Be carefull as filenames containing new line charcters would count as more than 1

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't think I've ever seen a filename in the wild that has a newline

Answer (score 3):

With GNU find, this might be slightly faster:

```
find . -name '*.TXT' -printf x | wc -m
```

Or with POSIX

```
find . -name '*.TXT' -exec printf x%.s {} + | wc -m
```

Comment: almost correct and performant, but the correct flag to use to count characters is `wc -m`

Comment: This approach also counts the current directory. To avoid this, add `-mindepth 1`. Another tip: the correct flag to use to count characters is `wc -m`, as `wc -c` counts bytes (almost the same for ascii chars, but can lead to unexpected results if not properly handled)

Comment: @MarcoCarloMoriggi Fair enough, might as well count chars rather than bytes, but it does not count the current directory, since current directory (`.`) does not match `*.TXT`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
find . -name '*TXT' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

with bash:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
```

and then, either

```
files=(**/*.TXT)
nfiles=${#files[@]}
```

or

```
nfiles=$( printf "%s\n" **/*.TXT | wc -l )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of questions about counting files.
Just for naming a few:

- [Is there a bash command which counts files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307257/is-there-a-bash-command-which-counts-files)
- [Counting total files in directory - find vs ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128759/counting-total-files-in-directory-find-vs-ls)
- [The fastest way to count the number of files in a directory (including subdirectories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652501/the-fastest-way-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-including-subdirect)
- ...

## Trying to summarize as much as I can

use this approach:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name '*TXT' -printf x | wc -m
```

The explanantion is simple: print an "x" for each item found in the current directory (recoursively, so if you don't need to recurse into inner subfolder, simply add `-maxdepth 1`), then count the characters. This way you no longer have to deal with odd file names and will get a huge improvement in time and memory.

If you are not yet conviced see [the explanation of the command](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-mindepth+1+-printf+x+%7C+wc+-m) on explainshell