# How can I create a file with null bytes in the filename?

Tags: bash, null, filenames

For a security test, I need to pass a file that contains null characters in its content and its filename.

For the body content, it's easy to use `printf`:

```
$ printf "Hello\00, Null!" > containsnull.txt
$ xxd contains.null
0000000: 4865 6c6c 6f00 2c20 4e75 6c6c 21         Hello., Null!
```

But how can I create a file with the null bytes in the name?

Note: A solution in `bash`, `python` or `nodejs` is preferred if possible

Comment: `NUL` is an illegal character in a filename on every file system I am aware of.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename posix doesn't allow null character .

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: *How is NUL an illegal character?* Since most OSs use C style strings (as opposed to RL strings or Pascal strings) the filename string uses a NUL to determine the end of the filename string. You might be able to coerce a string to contain a NUL, but very unlikely you will be able to deal with the resulting file.

Comment: Variable names or file names cannot contain NUL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to create a file name containing a null byte through POSIX or Windows APIs. On all the Unix systems that I'm aware of, it's impossible to create a file name containing a null byte, even with an ill-behaved application that bypasses the normal API, because the kernel itself treats all of its file name inputs as null-terminated strings. I believe this is true on Windows as well but I'm not completely sure.

As an application programmer, in terms of security, this means that you don't need to worry about a file name containing null bytes, if you're sure that what you have is the name of a file. On the other hand, if you're given a string and told to use it as a file name, for example if you're programming a server and letting the client choose file names, you need to ensure that this string does not contain null bytes. That's just one requirement among others including the string length, the presence of a directory separator (`/` or `\`), reserved names (`.` and `..`, reserved Windows file names such as `nul.txt` or `prn`), etc. On most Unix systems, on their native filesystem, the constraints for a file name are: no null byte or slash, length between 1 and some maximum, and the two names `.` and `..` are reserved. Windows, and non-native filesystems on Unix, have additional constraints (it's possible to put a `/` in a file name through direct kernel calls on Windows).

To put a null byte in a file's contents, just write a string to a file using any language that allows null bytes in strings. In bash, you cannot store a null byte in a string, so you need to use another method such as `printf '\0'` or `echo "abc" | tr b '\0'`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to worry about file names containing null bytes on Unixes and Windows because they cannot.

However, a file names that is being treated as UTF-8 can specify the NUL character (U+0000) using invalid "overlong" sequences: two, three or four-byte UTF-8 sequences that have all zeros in their code point payload bits.

This can be a security issue. For instance, A UTF-8 decoder that doesn't check for this can end up generating a `wchar_t` character value of 0 which then unexpectedly terminates the wide character string.

For instance, [the byte sequence C0 80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings) is an overlong encoding for NUL. This is evidently used by something called "Modified UTF-8" specifically for the purpose of encoding NUL characters that don't terminate the C string being used to hold the UTF-8.

If you're doing security testing, this is relevant; you can test whether programs are susceptible to NUL character (and other) injection via overlong encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$'\u000d'`

Not actually a null byte, but probably close enough to confuse people since you have to look really close to see that the last character is a D and not a 0, as it will usually print (if not just a blank) as the little box with hex codes in it.

Discovered this when I found a directory in my $HOME, named that...

Comment: More commonly known as \r.