# How to sort files based on filename length with subdirectories?

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to look at a directory named `Forever` where it has sub-directories with `Pure`,`Mineral` which are filled with `.csv` files. I was able to see all the `.csv` files in the directory, but I am having hard time sorting them according to the length of filename.

As for current directory, I am at `Forever`. So I am looking at both sub-directories `Pure` and `Mineral`.

What I did was:

`find -name ".*csv" | tr ' ' '_' | sort -n -r`

This just sorts the file reverse alphabetically, which doesn't consider the length.(I had to truncate some name of the files as it had spaces between them.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting file names by length of the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868408/sorting-file-names-by-length-of-the-file-name)

Comment: These questions might be similar (sorting based on filename length), but they're not the same; one accounts for subdirs while the other does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answer is more helpful than the marked duplicate because it also accounts for sub-dirs (which the dupe didn't):

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec bash -c 'echo -e $(wc -m <<< $(basename {}))\\t{}' \; | sort -nr | cut -f2
```

FWIW using `fd -e csv -x ...` was quite a bit faster for me (0.153s vs find's 2.084s)

*even though basename removes the file ext, it doesn't matter since find ensures that all of them have it*